# Generate Row_Number in SQL CE

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am using  SQL ce and I want to update a column of a database table as row number
something like this

update mytable set column=Row_Number()

Please suggest me how to achieve this in SQL ce query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IDENTITY column (must be type INT or bigint), it will increment as desired:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD MyID INT IDENTITY (100,1)
```

Comment: I want to update the column because identity may get deleted and never replaced that's why i want to update a column as row number.